# What is the (precise) meaning of "matrix-like?"

Tags: r, matrix, polymorphism, specifications

I would like to create "matrix-like" objects *that are not necessarily "proper" matrices*. But what, precisely, does "matrix-like" mean?

### Example 1

```
> image(1:9)
Error in image.default(1:9) : argument must be matrix-like
```

### Example 2

In the *R Language Definition* (in v3.3.1, §3.4.3) it is an [hapax legomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapax_legomenon) (emphasis added):

> [An] example of a class method for `[` is… if two indices are supplied (even if one is empty) it creates *matrix-like* indexing…

### Example 3

The title of `help(scale)` reads, "Scaling and Centering of *Matrix-like* Objects" (emphasis added). There seems to be a clue there:

> `numeric-alike` means that `as.numeric(.)` will be applied successfully if `is.numeric(.)` is not true.

Comment: Isn"t it a 2D objet? Something with two coordinates as index?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès  I think so, but I am looking for a precise definition.

Answer (score 5):

matrix-like data is data in tabular form, with the `dim` attribute set. But `length(dim(obj))` must be equal to 2, matrices are 2-dim objects.

Quoting from [Advanced R by Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html):

> **Matrices and arrays**
>
> Adding a dim attribute to an atomic vector allows it to behave like a
>   multi-dimensional array. A special case of the array is the matrix,
>   which has two dimensions. Matrices are used commonly as part of the
>   mathematical machinery of statistics. Arrays are much rarer, but worth
>   being aware of.
>
> Matrices and arrays are created with matrix() and array(), or by using
>   the assignment form of dim()

See also the `help("dim")` [page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dim.html).

Example:

```
x <- 1:9
image(x)    # error

y <- 1:9
dim(y) <- c(3, 3)
image(y)
```

[image]

Comment: That sounds precise. But can you point to any "official" documentation?

Comment: @AnaNimbus If you look at the `image.default` code, it does a test for: `if (is.null(dim(x))) stop("argument must be matrix-like")`. That's just an error message for one particular function so that's what that function thinks is "matrix-like." That's not a message the R language itself is returning.

Comment: @MrFlick It's interesting that the `image.default` test does not then also test for `length(dim(x))==2`

Comment: I see the quote from Hadley Wickham. That quote seems to be about _matrices_, not the concept "matrix-like." "Matrix-like" seems to be a wider concept. I will edit the question with another example shortly.

Comment: @AnaNimbus Matrix-like is not an R-concept. As MrFlick said, it is just a error message. Matrix-like just means 2D indexing.